# Jest test with TypeScript does not recognize import alias

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm setting up the tests for my web application, which works with the Vue framework with TypeScript, using the Jest framework. Everything seems to work alright, except with the `@` symbol in my imports, e.g., `import { Foo } from '@/bar`. Whether it's in my test files or in the source code, it doesn't understand it and returns:

```
Cannot find module '@/store' from 'src/tests/foo.spec.ts'
```

Here is my Jest configuration in `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "ts",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/tests/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": ["**/*.{ts,vue}", "!**/node_modules/**"],
    "coverageReporters": ["html", "text-summary"]
  }
```

Somebody has any idea how to make it work properly?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually found a solution, I appended this to my Jest configuration in `package.json`:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

From the `ts-jest` docs [path-mapping](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/) section:

```
// jest.config.js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils')
// In the following statement, replace `./tsconfig` with the path to your `tsconfig` file
// which contains the path mapping (ie the `compilerOptions.paths` option):
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig')

module.exports = {
  // [...]
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths /*, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' } */),
}
```